# Print variable PHP on tags HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

How can I use a variable from PHP on tags HTML inside of an array?

```
$row[] = '<a class="btn btn-round btn-info btn-icon btn-sm edit" href="contenidoFormula"  onclick="mostrar('."'".$FORMULA->id_formula."'".')"><i class="fas fa-search-plus"></i></a>
```

Instead of using onclick's JS function I want to use a PHP function with the same parameter, how can I do that?

Comment: You want to execute a PHP server side function, from a client side onclick javascript event?

Comment: FrankerZ You're right

Answer (score 0):

```
$row[] = "<a class='btn btn-round btn-info btn-icon btn-sm edit' href='contenidoFormula' onclick='mostrar(\"{$FORMULA->id_formula}\")'><i class='fas fa-search-plus'></i></a>";
```

given function: mostrar() is a javascript function. If it's PHP, then I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm Writing this code on a PHP CodeIgniter Controller. This shows a button option with a JS function but I want to send that PHP variable to it

Comment: @DevGnu then that's how you do it.